# when I vote a "downvote" also my reputation is decreases accordingly?

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

The subject is what I would to ask.

when I vote a "down votes" also my reputation is decreases accordingly?

This is (my) the case:: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3163353/1048235

Comment: Down-voting on posts costs you -1 point. Question downvoting is free.

Comment: That's how it's suppose to work, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) carefully.

Answer (score 1):

When you downvote an answer, your reputation will decrease by 1.

See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: I would downvote you for rep-whoring by answering a tired duplicate, but as a fellow rep whore I would rather keep my 1 reputation to myself.

Comment: @Bolt: even though I smell the tastefully flavored sarcasm, I would like to add that downvoting community wiki marked posts doesn't cost any reputation, either.

Comment: @Chichiray - To Bolts defence, I only CWd the answer after the comment :)

Comment: Hmm, strange, I already looked at the "answered" timestamp and compared it with Bolt's comment, but the edit timestamp isn't been taken into account. It's only visible in the history. I didn't expect that :)